# Does a sequentially continuous function take its supremum on compacts?

Tags: general-topology, probability-theory, product-space, first-countable

Consider the following situation: Let $X$ be a separable metric space [if this helps: I am mainly interested in the case $X = \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^d)$, the space of all Borel-probability measures on $\mathbb{R}^d$ with the topology of weak convergence of measures], $T$ a positive number and consider a function $F: X^{[0,T]} \to \mathbb{R}$, which is sequentially continuous when considering the product-topology of weak convergence of measures on $X^{[0,T]}.$

Note: The space $X^{[0,T]}$ is not first-countable (correct?), hence it is not clear whether $F$ is continuous.

My question: Does $F$ take its supremum on a compact subset $A \subseteq X^{[0,T]}$?

I could not find anything in the literature on this. I tried to show that $F$ is upper semicontinuous, but couldn't do that and I do not have another idea either.

I would very much appreciate any help!

Comment: $X^{[0,T]}$ is indeed not sequentially compact as $[0,T]$ has size continuum, so a compact $A$ inside it need not be sequentially compact either. If $A$ were sequentially compact, its image under $F$ would also be, and thus compact in $\mathbb{R}$, where these two notions *do* coincide. So it comes down to: what compact subspaces of a Tychonoff cube are sequentially compact?

Comment: As I am not an expert in general topology, please indicate if this summary is wrong in some places: If, in the above situation, $A$ is seq. comp., then the seq. cont. function $F$ takes its sup on $A$?

Comment: yes, but it’s gonna be hard to show sequential compactness of $A$.

Comment: In this case, would the preimage of the supremum be sequentially compact again? I assume it would. The thing is, I am only interested in certain $A$ - namely, in a specific $A$, which I can charakterize and describe and then, subsequently, I am only interestd in the preimage of the supremum on $A$.

Comment: If $F$ is seq. cont. and $a \in F[A]$ then $F^{-1}[\{a\}]$ is sequentially closed in $A$ (the argument is easy), and a sequentially closed subset of a sequentially compact space is sequentially compact (also easy argument), so yes.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is sequentially compact, then $F[A]$ is sequentially compact in $\mathbb{R}$ and thus compact (as the reals are a metric space in which these notions coincide) and $F[A]$ has a maximum, so assumes its supremum, say $a$. In the comments there was a further question on $A'=F^{-1}[\{a\}]$ which is easily seen to be sequentially closed when $F$ is sequentially continuous, and thus also sequentially compact as a sequentially closed subset of $A$.

It will be hard to apply this criterion, I think, as it's tricky to characterise sequentially compact subsets of a large product like $X^{[0,T]}$ which is itself non-sequentially compact (and not a sequential space either), e.g. many $\Sigma$-products are dense and sequentially compact in this product, as is well-known.
I believe some work has been done on this for $C_p$-spaces but I'm not aware of a general characterisation beyond the definition.

Comment: Thank you for your input! I very much appreciate your help on this. I refined my situation a little bit to the point that the set $A$, which concerns me, is known to be a subset of the set of all continuous functions from $[0,T]$ to $X$. The last senctence of your answer seems like this could be helpful?